# JAXB - XBRL, Unmarshalling XML file with Child element is not declared in (root element) XSD File

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xbrl

Is it possible to unmarshall all element of xml file which has condition that child elements are not declared in root element's XSD file.

You can see XML file below. gen:link, ea:existenceAssertion, variable:* schema (do not find the link but I have the files locally) are separated from link:linkbase schema (http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd), here is xml content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<link:linkbase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/generic http://www.xbrl.org/2008/generic-link.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/formula http://www.xbrl.org/2008/formula.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/label http://www.xbrl.org/2008/generic-label.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/reference http://www.xbrl.org/2008/generic-reference.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/consistency http://www.xbrl.org/2008/consistency-assertion.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/existence http://www.xbrl.org/2008/existence-assertion.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/value http://www.xbrl.org/2008/value-assertion.xstring http://xbrl.org/2008/filter/concept http://www.xbrl.org/2008/concept-filter.xstring http://xbrl.org/2010/message http://www.xbrl.org/2010/generic-message.xstring http://xbrl.org/2010/message/validation http://www.xbrl.org/2010/validation-message.xstring" xmlns:ca="http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/consistency" xmlns:meta="http://www.example.com/taxonomy/dictionary/2016/meta" xmlns:gen="http://xbrl.org/2008/generic" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"  xmlns:variable="http://xbrl.org/2008/variable" xmlns:xfi="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/function/instance" xmlns:cf="http://xbrl.org/2008/filter/concept" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:valm="http://xbrl.org/2010/message/validation" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:ea="http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/existence" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:validation="http://xbrl.org/2008/validation" xmlns:frm="http://www.example.com/taxonomy/dictionary/2016/frm" xmlns:formula="http://xbrl.org/2008/formula" xmlns:msg="http://xbrl.org/2010/message" xmlns:va="http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/value"  xmlns:label="http://xbrl.org/2008/label" xmlns:gf="http://xbrl.org/2008/filter/general" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance">
  <link:roleRef roleURI="http://www.xbrl.org/2010/role/message" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.xbrl.org/2010/generic-message.xstring#standard-message"/>
  <link:roleRef roleURI="http://www.example.com/taxonomy/role/Form1" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="Form1.xstring#Form1"/>
  <link:roleRef roleURI="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/role/link" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/generic-link.xstring#standard-link-role"/>
  <link:arcroleRef arcroleURI="http://xbrl.org/arcrole/2008/variable-filter" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/variable.xstring#variable-filter"/>
  <link:arcroleRef arcroleURI="http://xbrl.org/arcrole/2008/variable-set" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/variable.xstring#variable-set"/>
  <link:arcroleRef arcroleURI="http://xbrl.org/arcrole/2010/assertion-unsatisfied-message" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.xbrl.org/2010/validation-message.xstring#assertion-unsatisfied-message"/>
  <gen:link xlink:type="extended" xlink:role="http://www.example.com/taxonomy/role/Form1">
    <ea:existenceAssertion xlink:type="resource" xlink:label="Exist_string30" xlink:title="Exist_string30" id="Exist_string30" test=". =1" aspectModel="dimensional" implicitFiltering="true"/>
    <variable:factVariable xlink:type="resource" xlink:label="Fact_string30" xlink:title="Fact_string30" id="Fact_string30" bindAsSequence="false"/>
    <variable:variableArc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://xbrl.org/arcrole/2008/variable-set" xlink:from="Exist_string30" xlink:to="Fact_string30" xlink:title="Exist_string30 to Fact_string30" priority="0" order="1.0" name="string30"/>
    <cf:conceptName xlink:type="resource" xlink:label="cf_string30" xlink:title="cf_string30" id="cf_string30">
      <cf:concept>
        <cf:qname>meta:string30</cf:qname>
      </cf:concept>
    </cf:conceptName>
    <variable:variableFilterArc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://xbrl.org/arcrole/2008/variable-filter" xlink:from="Fact_string30" xlink:to="cf_string30" xlink:title="Fact_string30 to cf_string30" priority="0" order="1.0" cover="true" complement="false"/>
    <msg:message xlink:type="resource" xlink:label="EAmsg_string30" xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2010/role/message" xlink:title="EAmsg_string30" xml:lang="id" id="EAmsg_string30">error message of this</msg:message>
    <gen:arc xlink:type="arc" xlink:arcrole="http://xbrl.org/arcrole/2010/assertion-unsatisfied-message" xlink:from="Exist_string30" xlink:to="EAmsg_string30" xlinbask:title="Exist_string30 to EAmsg_string30" priority="0" order="1.0"/>
  </gen:link>
<link:linkbase>
```

I use maven-jaxb2-plugin to do XJC for all xbrl schema (link:linkbase, variable:*, gen:link, ea:existenceAssertion, etc) below is sample of generation result of Linkbase.java. (please tell me if you need more.)

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.3.0 
// See <a href="https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/">https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2020.06.11 at 06:41:40 AM ICT 
//


package bani.hasyim.xsd.xbrl.p2003.linkbase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRefs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import bani.hasyim.xsd.xbrl.p2003.xl.ExtendedType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
 *       &lt;choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"&gt;
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase}documentation"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase}roleRef"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase}arcroleRef"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink}extended"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/choice&gt;
 *       &lt;attribute name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}ID" /&gt;
 *       &lt;anyAttribute processContents='lax' namespace='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'/&gt;
 *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "linkbase")
public class Linkbase {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "documentation", namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase", type = LinkbaseDocumentationType.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "roleRef", namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "arcroleRef", namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "extended", namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<?>> documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String id;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    /**
     * Gets the value of the documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getDocumentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link LinkbaseDocumentationType }
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link RoleRef }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ArcroleRef }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link FootnoteLink }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LabelLink }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ReferenceLink }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PresentationLink }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link DefinitionLink }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link CalculationLink }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ExtendedType }{@code >}
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<JAXBElement<?>> getDocumentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef() {
        if (documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef == null) {
            documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<?>>();
        }
        return this.documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
     * 
     * <p>
     * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
     * the value is the string value of the attribute.
     * 
     * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
     * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     *     always non-null
     */
    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }

}
```

is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Just add these elements to your `documentationOrRoleRefOrArcroleRef` property.

Comment: @lexicore, Do i have to unmarshall gen:link, ea:existenceAssertion, variable:* separately and set java object manually ?

Comment: i'm expecting, only with following code, Linkbase and all the children in xml file will be unmarshalled.




JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Linkbase.class);
        Linkbase linkbase = (Linkbase) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new FileInputStream(new File(file)));